# Проблемы с transform: rotate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Имеется рулетка, крутится - вертится, и всё хорошо если бы не один нюанс.

Каждые `10 секунд` рулетка должна крутиться на `1080deg` и стартовать с предыдущего места.

Но если перейти на другую вкладку и подождать пару минут и вернуться обратно то рулетка не крутилась и собирала `deg` в кучу, то есть за 2 минуты `12960deg` на собиралось и как бешеная начинает крутить не дожидаясь очереди прокрутки, это очень портит картину проекта, как решить?

Спасибо

```
$(".rullet").css({
    transform: "rotate(" + (parseInt(current_position_rullet) +    (three_scroll - left_scroll) + (index * 24) + randomInteger(-8, 8)) +    "deg)"
});
```

Полный код : https://jsfiddle.net/m4kw6e10/2/

Comment: приостанавливать действие скрипта при потере вкладкой фокуса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта проблема связана не с css, а с js. Механику проблемы не знаю, но делаю так как описал ниже.

Есть вариант проверять активно ли окно и крутить рулетку только если оно активно.

Ставим флаг активности:

```
window.onblur = function() { window.blurred = true; };
window.onfocus = function() { window.blurred = false; };
```

И проверку в интервал:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if ( window.blurred ) { return; }
});
```

Comment: Как ни как, но я воспользуюсь этим решением, спасибо, помогло.